# Create an unordered list tree from nested object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, list, object, dom

I have a nested object like this:

```
const countries = {
  "Europe": {
    "France": {},
    "Spain": {}
  },
  "America": {
    "North": {
      "USA": {},
      "Canada": {}
    },
    "South": {
      "Brazil": {},
      "Argentina": {}
    }
  }
};
```

And I want to create an unordered list from it like this one:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Europe:
    <ul>
      <li>France</li>
      <li>Spain</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    America:
    <ul>
      <li>
        North:
        <ul>
          <li>USA</li>
          <li>Canada</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        South:
        <ul>
          <li>Brazil</li>
          <li>Argentina</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And it shouldn't have any empty lists in the end.

So far I tried this recursive approach, but it just returns a list with 2 items `[object Object]`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>data tree</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const countries = {
        "Europe": {
          "France": {},
          "Spain": {}
        },
        "America": {
          "North": {
            "USA": {},
            "Canada": {}
          },
          "South": {
            "Brazil": {},
            "Argentina": {}
          }
        }
      };

      //Getting the container were I want to put my list
      let container = document.getElementById('container');

      function createTree(container, data) {
        //Recursive function which will create as much lists as I need
        function rec(obj) {
          let list = document.createElement('ul');
          //Looping through the object properties
          for (let item in obj){
            //If the object property is object too
            //And it has its own properties
            //Then create a list ite for it 
            //And put a new list in it with the recursion
            if (Object.keys(obj[item]).length) {
              let listItem = document.createElement('li');
              listItem.textContent += obj[item];
              list.appendChild(listItem);
              rec(obj[item]);
            }
          }
          
          return list;
        }

        //In the end add the list to the container
        container.appendChild(rec(data));
      }

      createTree(container, countries);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If there's any way to do it with other approaches like loops or anything else, it would be acceptable too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign to the content of the created `li` on each iteration regardless - *then* check if the associated object has any keys, and if so, perform the recursive call:

```js
const countries = {
  "Europe": {
    "France": {},
    "Spain": {}
  },
  "America": {
    "North": {
      "USA": {},
      "Canada": {}
    },
    "South": {
      "Brazil": {},
      "Argentina": {}
    }
  }
};

function createTree(container, data) {
  const ul = container.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(data)) {
    const li = ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    li.textContent = key;
    if (Object.keys(val).length) {
      createTree(li, val);
    }
  }
}

createTree(document.getElementById('container'), countries);
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

I guess if you really wanted to you could use a DocumentFragment instead:

```js
const countries = {
  "Europe": {
    "France": {},
    "Spain": {}
  },
  "America": {
    "North": {
      "USA": {},
      "Canada": {}
    },
    "South": {
      "Brazil": {},
      "Argentina": {}
    }
  }
};

function createTree(container, data) {
  const ul = container.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(data)) {
    const li = ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    li.textContent = key;
    if (Object.keys(val).length) {
      createTree(li, val);
    }
  }
}

const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
createTree(frag, countries);
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(frag);
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: If performance isn't a concern this is probably just fine. However if it is, is it worth considering using a document fragment or just a plain old `innerHTML` when we're done processing the object?

Comment: Unless there are literally tens of thousands of nodes, it shouldn't matter. Performance isn't an issue in 99% of situations - better to concentrate on clean, short, readable code. The browser will only repaint once all Javascript is completely finished anyway.

Comment: It seems like I was in the right way, but I went too far and made it very hard for me. Thank you very much, it looks way cleaner and readable!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to CertainPerformance's answer. I tried with a nested object tree which had some properties with string values like:

```js
var k1 = {
  k11:{
     k111:'111'
     }
  }
```

and the recursion crashed the chrome-page.

So I changed this:

```js
li.textContent = key;
if (Object.keys(val).length) {
    createTree(li, val);
}
```

to this:

```js
if (Object.keys(val).length && isObj(val)){
    li.textContent = key;
    createTree(li,val);
} else {
    li.textContent = key + ' : ' + val;
}
```

and added:

```
isObj = function(obj) {return obj === Object(obj);}
```

(before the createTree function)